# Is it possible to use reflection to load and invoke a method in a DLL that is of a higher .net framework?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-4.7.2

I have an application that uses reflection to load a .dll and invoke a method with parameters. reflection module was built using .net 4.5
This has worked for us for years.
we have recently tried to use a dll that was built using .net4.7.2 and the reflection module excepts on the invoke call, but the method is not the cause of the exception, as that method has an exception handler that would log the error. that it not even reached, it seems to fail at the moment of invoke.

this is the faulting code ("plugin" here is the .net4.7.2 isolated assembly that has the method to be invoked):

```
        object objRef = null;
        using((objRef as IDisposable)) {
            objRef = Activator.CreateInstance(plugin.type);
            MethodInfo methodToInvoke;
            if(plugin.methods[method].Count == 1) {
                methodToInvoke = plugin.methods[method].Values.Single();
            } else {
                // get the hashcode for all the names of the types; use this as the key
                var parameterHash = args.Select(arg => arg.GetType().Name.GetHashCode()).Aggregate(0, (res, next) => res | next);
                methodToInvoke = plugin.methods[method][parameterHash];
            }
            return methodToInvoke.Invoke(objRef, args);
        }
```

the result is an unhandled exception:

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>   StackTrace
>      at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>      at FactSet.IS.Core.Infrastructure.PluginManager.IsolatedAssembly.Invoke(String activator, String method, Object[] args)
>      at FactSet.IS.Core.Infrastructure.PluginManager.IsolatedAssembly.Invoke(String activator, String method, Object[] args)
>      at FactSet.IS.Core.Infrastructure.PluginManager.PluginAppDomain.IsolatedAssemblyInvoke(String handler, String method, Object[] args)
>   Inner Message
>   Configuration system failed to initialize

I do not know what "Configuration system failed to initialize" means

Comment: Configuration system failed to initialize means your **configuration** section in **web.config** file should start with **configSections**. Or in other words **The first element in configuration should be configSections**.

Comment: Its an app.config, it produces a <libraryname>.dll.config to go with the <libraryname>.dll... and none of the other dlls that do work have a <configsections> section. 
They just have an XML declaration and a <configuration> section. 
The XML in the config is not malformed. 
the only difference in the config is that the Startup section says     
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
as opposed to  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2"
which leads into my whole question about versions

Comment: If there is only one [`supportedRuntime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/startup/supportedruntime-element?redirectedfrom=MSDN) in your app.config it's all right, don't touch it. But if there is a duplicate like this: `<supportedRuntime version="v3.5" />` with different version remove the duplicate and keep the first one.

Comment: That's impossible, as though you can reflect on the IL code, it won't run on old version of CLR.

Comment: If the message is `Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.` the has to be an inner exception. Can you provide that full inner exception?

Comment: It says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: I resolved the issue. When I changed the .net framework to be the same as the loading application, I was still having  an issue, and it turned out to be a slight typo in the config file. 
Both isses needed addressing for it to work